# H2 Mixed Mode and DBeaver

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, dbeaver

I am trying to connect to a local database in a Spring application, which puts H2 in mixed mode. I am trying to connect to Dbeaver, but I get the following message:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: Nombre de usuario ó password incorrecto
Wrong user name or password [28000-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:461)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:170)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServer.checkKeyAndGetDatabaseName(TcpServer.java:527)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Nombre de usuario ó password incorrecto
Wrong user name or password [28000-200]
```

DBeaver:

[Parameters and URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dH5WF.png)

Properties in Spring:

```
server.port = 8080
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/demo;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;AUTO_SERVER_PORT=9090;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;PASSWORD=password;USER=sa
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I tried various things and I can't connect from DBeaver. Did anyone have a similar problem? Thank you very much to all!

Answer (score 1):

You can connect only on local machine.

For that choose in Connect by URL and enter your url there. For connect on server you can use only with browser console http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode

[DBeaver image. How to connect to local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJUks.png)